# Set object properties using a string

Tags: c#, class

I have a console app that accepts 8 parameters
Its getting a little confusing so I wondered if it would be possible to do something like this - we'll make it short for the example:
I'll make a class called userData which will have 3 properties

```
class userData
{
    public string Dir { get; set; }
    public string FileFilter { get; set; }
    public string OutPutFile { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to make a string as such:

```
"{dir=\"c:\\\", FileFilter=\"*.txt\", OutPutFile=\"c:\\op.txt\"}"
```

Then the program can automatically assign the class properties according to that string
Something like eval function in JavaScript

Is this possible?
Is there any other suggestions?

Thanks
David

Comment: I think you have a classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Rather than asking for help on what you think might be the solution, you should focus more on the problem.  Why are you trying to set properties with a string?  Where does the data come from? User input? An external data source?

Comment: if you are taking JSON string as input, then you could use JSON deserializer to convert json strin gto userData object. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Having difficulty understanding what you want to do. Maybe due to confusion between "class" and "object". Once a class is instantiated it is called an object, and I think maybe you want to modify the object, not the class?

Comment: @RenniePet, correct. I want to create a new object of that class filling its properties using that string.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - I'll explain. This app is a console app which myself or any other user will be sending parameters to it telling it what to do. Instead of sending 8 different parameters, I wanted to send one string as I described above. I hope its clear now.

Comment: @DaveyD it is still not clear.  Where are these 8 parameters coming from?  Are they command line arguments?  How are they being sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the input as JSON string (with proper escaping):

```
"{ \"Dir\" : \"c:\", \"FileFilter\" : \"*.txt\", \"OutPutFile\" : \"c:\\op.txt\"}"
```

Then use DataContractJsonSerializer to serialize this input string to userData object:

```csharp
class Program2
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        String str = args[0];//check for length and handle error scenarios.
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));

        //deserialize
        try
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(UserData));
            UserData data = (UserData)ser.ReadObject(ms);

            Console.WriteLine(data.Dir + ", " + data.FileFilter + ", " + data.OutPutFile );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
class UserData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Dir { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string FileFilter { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string OutPutFile { get; set; }
}
```

[Doc for DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hi gp! This is exactly what I was looking for! I am just having a problem with the colons in my paths. It is seeing the colon as a new separator. Is there a way to escape it or something like that?

Comment: I would use NewtonSoft JSON parser instead of DataContractJsonSerializer.

Comment: Colon in value is not required to be escaped. See the updated input in my answer.

Comment: @Dan-o any good JSON parser/deserializer is fine. Idea is to take JSON string input and convert to typed object and use it.

Comment: @gp - Thanks. I see what you are saying, but I am still getting an error message - I guess its because of the slash. Using the latest user input, I get an error message "Encountered unexpected character 'o'. Which would be the last value c:\\op.txt. Why??  However, I did realize that if you change the double backslash to 1 forward slash, everything works perfect.

Comment: Feel free to fix the input to make it work for you. This input did work for me though.